# Multiple database connection not working with new_link=TRUE and sql.safe_mode = OFF

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-connect

I'm tryng to connect a different database from a php function (assuming there's a current connection to another database). I'm using `mysql_connect()` with `new_link` parameter set to TRUE as you can see below. How is it possible the following code returns `global_thread_id=16357138 local_thread_id=16357139 current_global=16357139` (meaning local connection overriden previous connection) despite the TRUE in mysql_connect()

Also in php settings, **sql.safe_mode = OFF**

```
// Class static method
static function Query($sql) {
       $global_thread_id = mysql_thread_id();
       if ($link = mysql_connect(FB_DB_HOST, FB_DB_USER, FB_DB_PASS, true)) 
       {
            $local_thread_id = mysql_thread_id($link);                          
            echo 'global_thread_id='.$global_thread_id.' local_thread_id='.$local_thread_id.' current_global='.mysql_thread_id();   
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_thread_id() fetch the latest thread id, not a "global"

php manual for [mysql_thread_id](http://se.php.net/mysql_thread_id) says:

> Retrieves the current thread ID

```
// Class static method
static function Query($sql) {

       /* fetch latest thread id = global */
       $global_thread_id = mysql_thread_id();
       if ($link = mysql_connect(FB_DB_HOST, FB_DB_USER, FB_DB_PASS, true)) 
       {
            /* fetch thread id from $link */
            $local_thread_id = mysql_thread_id($link);

            /* echo 2 vars and the latest thread id = same as link */
            echo 'global_thread_id='.$global_thread_id.' local_thread_id='.$local_thread_id.' current_global='.mysql_thread_id();   
       }
}
```

Comment: yes I know. What I mean by "global" is my script has a main connection used everywhere on the page thus the mysql_thread_id() without $link to fetch this main thread ID (hence I call it global connection) and for this second connection I'm using the $link resource to fetch what I call "local" thread id...

Comment: now my issue is the thread ID returned by mysql_thread_id() equals $local_thread_id after the mysql_connect() call despite the 'new_link' parameter set to TRUE

Comment: if you have more then one database connection, always use the $link varibale when talking with mysql, my usal approach is to have a database class, where i set the $link as a class variable. but if you going to fix all your mysql-calls, you may want to move from thous old depricated functions to PDO